# Reputation Changes Automagically?

Tags: support, reputation

My StackOverflow reputation got decreased 20 but I cannot see any new event in the history, not even a deleted question or down vote or anything.

Going through all how reputation works and how reputation system changed, etc just confused me more, so, forgive me if this feels like a duplicate to you. I "did" search and wasn't sure of the appropriate one.

Comment: Extremely quick unupvotes /unaccept that are immediately after an upvote/accept don't show even though you see your rep fluctuate. Are you sure you have "show deleted posts" checked?

Comment: Convert that to an answer and I will accept it. I remember seeing deleted question before so I thought this was the default, didn't remember / notice that I need to check some checkbox or so. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be due to "show removed posts" being unticked at the bottom of the page.

Alternatively, it can be this:

If an unaccept/unupvote/whatever is done within xyz seconds of the corresponding accept/upvote, the rep counter fluctuates (due to the magic realtime updates), but the history doesn't show it.

This is to prevent fickle users from flooding your rep history{*}.

<sup>Happened to me yesterday, my Chem.SE rep kept fluctuating every half a minute since an OP kept switching the accept tick between mine and someone else's answer.</sup>

Comment: Well, that wasn't it. It wasn't a matter of time I think (was a deleted question that I answered and got upvoted) but a matter of not checking "show removed posts" checkbox (didn't notice it), which you prompted me to note in your comment on the question itself.

Comment: @MohamedMeligy: Whoops, misread you comment as "I know its already ticked since I saw a deleted post before". Fixed